# Compiler generates default move constructor when it shouldn't

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, move-semantics

from N3337:

> If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move
>   constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only
>   if
>
> X does not have a user-declared copy constructor, X does not have a
>   user-declared copy assignment operator, X does not have a
>   user-declared move assignment operator, X does not have a
>   user-declared destructor, and the move constructor would not be
>   implicitly defined as deleted.

The first question is: why compiler generates move constructor when it shouldn't (there is user declared destructor and other functions which  prevents generation of move constructor). 
Example program below prints `constructorCounter=5` which means that there used move constructor (without move operations value::constructorCounter should be 10)

```
#include <iostream>

class value {
    public:
        value() {
            ++constructorCounter;
        }
        value(const int value)
            : _value(value)
        {
            ++constructorCounter;
        }
        value(const value& other)
            : _value(other._value)
        {
            ++constructorCounter;
        }
        const value& operator=(const value& rhs) {
            _value = rhs._value;
            return _value;
        }
        ~value() { }
        static int constructorCounter;
    private:
        int _value;
};

int value::constructorCounter = 0;

class array {
    public:
        //  array() = delete;
        //  array(array&&) = delete;
        array(const int size)
            : _size(size), _values(new value[size])
        {
            std::clog << "array(const int size)" << std::endl;
        }
        array(const array& rhs)
            : array(rhs._size)
        {
            std::clog << "array(const array& rhs)" << std::endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
                _values[i] = rhs._values[i];
        }
        array& operator=(const array&) {
            std::clog << "array& operator=(const array&)" << std::endl;
        }
        ~array() {
            delete [] _values;
        }
    private:
        value* _values;
        int _size;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    array c(array(5));
    std::clog << "constructor counter=" << value::constructorCounter << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Second related question: why program fail to compile if i disable move `constructor array(array&&) = deleted;`, why there is no 'fall back' to copy consturctor `array(const array&)` ?

Comment: `array c(array(5));` _array(5)_ is an *rvalue*, therefore the move constructor will be called.

Answer (score 10):

At first, the line:

```
array c(array(5));
```

Leads to the copy constructor being used (because there is no user declared move constructor). However since it happens to be the `c` object construction, the compiler is able to elide the copy and construct your `array` object in-place.

Now when you *user-declare* the move constructor as `delete`-d, it is considered during overload resolution and indeed while resolving the call in line:

```
array c(array(5));
```

`array(array&&)` will be a perfect match... But it is deleted so overload resolution stops (perfect match), and an error is output (the function is deleted).

As suggested in comments, would you have been using the C++17 standard for your compilation, the line

```
array c(array(5));
```

Would have resulted in a guaranteed copy elision since it fits the following scenario:

> In initialization, if the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the class of the destination, the initializer expression is used to initialize the destination object

Rendering your code strictly equivalent to:

```
array c(5);
```

Comment: Even though the Q is not tagged with C++17 you might want to mention that in C++17 it wont mater if the move constructor is deleted, it will still elide the copy

Answer (score 3):

Move constructors are not generated here. Pedantically, the move constructor and assignment are not declared in this case.

What you observe is the compiler elides copying in `array c(array(5));`. See [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) for more details:

> In initialization, if the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the class of the destination, the initializer expression is used to initialize the destination object:
>
> ```
> T x = T(T(T())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x
> ```

---

When you do `array(array&&) = deleted;` the above expression considers the move constructor now (it was previously not declared) and fails because it is deleted.